# Most efficient const char* comparison being case insensitive

Tags: c++, performance, optimization

Would anyone please be able to tell me the most efficient way to compare two constant char stars?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    const char* value1 = "hello";
    const char* value2 = "HELLO";
    const char* possibility = NULL;


    if(stricmp(value1, value2)==0)
    {
        std::cout <<"\nThey Match!!!!!" << std::endl;
    }
    else{std::cout << "\nThey dont match :("<< std::endl;}

    return 0;
}
```

I used the following standard function but I know its not the most efficient way to do this?

Besides `stricmp` cannot handle NULL which in my case has a possibility of occurring.

So is there any other alternatives good for performance?

Thanks in advance

Comment: How do you "know" this is not the most efficient way? Did you measure the alternatives? Actually, did you measure *this* method? What's your performance requirement?

Comment: why do you think its not efficient ? it would depend on how stricmp is implemented which would be platform specific and usually they are well optimized.

Comment: `using namespace std;` without using *everything* in that namespace is far less efficient than anything `strcmp` is doing.

Comment: This was a basic example . . . illustration . . . I couldnt paste up my actual source that would just be very "hard" to see the main focus of my problem.

Comment: Would be far more interesting though ;-)

Comment: I guess your right for me asking such a question, have edited the example to reflect it AJG85 :D

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no efficient way to compare two character strings.

There are a couple of ways to improve on the basic `stricmp()`, if it shows up very high on a profile (which I have seen in real apps). You may find that the bulk of the cost is in `tolower()`, which is a function called on each character to convert it from upper to lowercase before comparison. The overhead of this function call, plus the cost of its body, can add up to significant time, because it must be locale-sensitive and deal with letters like Ö. If you know that your comparisons will only ever be performed in one locale (ie, only in English), then you can speed up tolower() by building a 256-character ASCII lookup table and implementing stricmp() manually.

With GCC, if you know you are targeting a CPU that supports SSE3, you can also specify the `-msse3` command line switch that generates slightly more efficient machine instructions for the string comparison. It mostly helps case *sensitive* comparison, however.

In my line of work, any algorithm that requires comparing lots of constant character strings, as opposed to using interns or symbols to represent such identifiers, is considered a code smell. On one project, profiling indicated that about 7% of the CPU time was spent inside tolower() inside `stricmp`. That is effectively 7 out of 100 machines per data center doing nothing but turning uppercase letters into lowercase ones.

Comment: Crashworks thank you for that insight, im currently looking into switch, very interesting take on the problem im having.its interesting you point out the .tolower() cost and the means in which this can be decreased. Thank you for that :)

Comment: @GgGg You should run a sampling profiler on your application and make sure that `tolower()` really is a performance issue before you take that extreme measure. It is not always a problem; it depends heavily on what compiler you are using and your particular usage patterns.

Comment: Thanks again, seems as tho .tolower is the main hogger for me. I think ill go for that compiler switch to be honest, I got 2 days and this is the key I was looking for. Thanks again!

Comment: @GgGg  If you are setting that flag, try also setting `-mfpmath=sse`, which will speed up all of your floating point math a little bit.

Answer (score 2):

`stricmp` is probably faster than anything you can write yourself, and you shouldn't bother unless you know that this will be the bottleneck in your program's performance.

Comment: I've been on many projects where stricmp() was a major performance bottleneck (the *top* function on the profile), and was much improved by writing a custom stricmp().  (Not improved as much as it would have been by catching needlessly compare strings during code review in the first place, but sadly not every programmer realizes how costly they are.)

Comment: I agree this is a costly implementation when the number of calls made to it is on a large scale

Comment: Trusting the system APIs  is no way to get better as a programmer. They were written by busy people, just like you.